# Is it possible to have simplewallet start scanning from a certain block instead of the beginning of the blockchain when refreshing a new wallet?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli

Say I generate a new wallet, and I know for sure that I don't have any transactions appearing prior to block 'X'.

Is it possible to instruct simplewallet to start the scan at a certain block? I'd like to be able to do refresh 'X', or set the last block on the wallet as a command (simplewallet --set-last-block {wallet_name} {block_num}).

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/113/do-i-need-to-sync-the-entire-blockchain-before-i-can-send-a-transaction/120#120

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the current code in git, yes there is a --restore-height parameter that does what you want. But for a newly created wallet, simplewallet will find out the current last block from the daemon, and set this parameter automatically, so you don't even need to specify it.

This feature will be in the next release (v0.10.0). With this feature a newly created wallet can sync to a daemon on localhost in just a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

New wallets will automatically skip blocks before the creation time (technically, they will request only block hash info from the daemon for those early blocks, which is much faster). Note that this requires a newer daemon as well, so this will not work if you connect to a third party daemon which has not been updated yet.